# How to assign "grid-area" property from javaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid, grid-layout

I am building a checkers game and all my squares are HTML div's with the     `id` property describing their position (e.g. '8a', '7b' etc.). I would like to iterate through the board object in JS, get value of this     `id`, and then assign it to the value of
  `gridArea` of the given square (I already prepared the 
    `gridTemplateArea` in the wrapper's css), because I don't want to do it manually. 
My program gets the id value, but after assigning it to *[square]*.style.templateArea nothing happens... the value is not there.

I've even tried to use template literals like this `${itsId}`, but still nothing.

```
let boardEl = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
for(let square of boardEl) {
   let itsId = square.id;
   square.style.gridArea = itsId;
}
```

When I console.log gridArea of any square, its value is "";
I would like it to be equal to the square's id.

Comment: Does `boardEl` end up with any elements? (Can you show your HTML?) If it's empty, the `for` loop won't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

I have been passing through the same hassle, and the way I solved it is like the following:

In js(or DOM) the `gridArea` property is not used to assign names to grid items. Instead it's

> used as a shorthand property for the grid-row-start,
>   grid-column-start, grid-row-end and the grid-column-end properties

. In other words the css equivalents for the right applications are like: `grid-area: 1 / 2 / 5 / 6;` or `grid-area: 2 / 1 / span 2 / span 3;` or just `grid-area: 2 / 1;` and **NOT** for the `grid-area: myArea;` format. So it better you rearange your code to assign grid areas in terms of column and row numbers and/or spans. Possible like:

```
square.style.gridArea = 'rowStart / columnStart';
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-area.asp or https://www.w3docs.com/learn-css/grid-area.html

Answer (score 0):

You need **one** CSS rule for **every** board location to set the grid-area:

```
[id="A1"] {
    grid-area: A1;
}
```

Instead of using `id` I used an `at` attribute because it makes more sense (semantic HTML)
in a  Chessboard prototype: https://chessmeister.github.io/
to demonstrate the power of W3C standard Custom Elements over React.

[image]

```css
chessmeister-board-layer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 12.5%);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 12.5%);
    grid-template-areas:
        "A8 B8 C8 D8 E8 F8 G8 H8"
        "A7 B7 C7 D7 E7 F7 G7 H7"
        "A6 B6 C6 D6 E6 F6 G6 H6"
        "A5 B5 C5 D5 E5 F5 G5 H5"
        "A4 B4 C4 D4 E4 F4 G4 H4"
        "A3 B3 C3 D3 E3 F3 G3 H3"
        "A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2 G2 H2"
        "A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1 G1 H1";
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    user-select: none;
}
```

and then position pieces with (64 CSS rules):

```
[at="A1"] {
    grid-area: A1;
}
.
.
.
[at="H8"] {
    grid-area: H8;
}
```

[image]